# How to estimate the size of a git version?

Tags: jgit

I would like to estimate the size of a git commit for one file? We are using jgit to store versions for some internal files and i would like to estimate how much the a new commit for one file increases the size of the git repository.
Any suggestions?

UPDATE: The files we store in git are yaml text files.
When I commit a changed version of a yaml file I do not see any significant change of the .git
[image: original commit]
[image: new commit -> observing change in size]
[image: new commit -> observing change in size]

Comment: What is a "new version" for you? Just a tag/branch?

Comment: Thanks @RogerLindsjö I updated my question. A "new version" is a commit but I am interested in only a specific file (not all the files in the commit).

Comment: If you calculate the size of the `.git` directory before and after making the commit, you should get an estimate of the size of the commit.

Comment: Thanks @RüdigerHerrmann the .git directory is unchanged from the size point of view when I commit a changed file to the repo.

Comment: You can use `du -s .git` to show the total size of the git directory (including all its contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer ignores pack files.)

Git would have to store one new blob and some insignificant metadata (like the commit message). If you `zlib` the file and inspect its size you will get a good estimate of how much the repo will grow.

Comment: The files we store in git are yaml text files. @actual_panda What do you mean when you say "zlib" the file and the "answer ignores pack files"?

Comment: @AnaSustic Git will compress the yaml file with the program `zlib` and store it away in the .git directory. That's the bulk of the data your new commit will add to the repository.  (Unless it's a very small file, in which case the metadata like commit message or commit date may become significant). Git also has a special mechanism to compress the data further (called pack files) but how much space using pack files will save you depends on the repo.